# is it possible to define relationships in Eloquent models if tables are in different databases?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

There are two tables which are in different databases. Let's say one of them is Users and another is Cars. Cars has column 'user_id' in it. Is it possible to create models for these two tables (Car and User), so that I could eager load the relations when I query Users?
Like this:

```
User::find(3)->with('cars')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible the short way. You can do this by setting up different connections, but this does not conform to relational database policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for databases which support this like Microsoft SQL server as a driver. All you have to do to make this work is add multiple connections (databases) in your config and reference them in your model:

```
protected $connection = 'database2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried it out and It turned out that laravel works well in such situation. All you need is to specify connections on your models, and define relations as usually. The point is that laravel does not create one big query when you use Model::with('relation'). First It queries root model, then child's model and then matches them  right in the code. though I find it strange for it must reduce performance since we have two queries instead of one and then It processes result, though it works well with cross database relations.